# My view won´t derive from ViewPage<MyViewModel>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a total newbie with ASP NET MVC

I'm trying to make the view Index.aspx inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage[FeaturedProductsViewModel] by declaring it as:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<FeaturedProductsViewModel>" %>
```

But I get this error message:

```
The view at '~/Views/Home/Index.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>
```

FeaturedProductsViewModel (which I expect to be the TModel for this view) is declared in the Models folder:

[image]

The view Index.aspx starts with:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Ploeh.Samples.Commerce.Web.Models" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<FeaturedProductsViewModel>" %>
```

FeaturedProductsViewModel is located in the Ploeh.Samples.Commerce.Web.Models namespace.

**Do I need to state somewhere that FeaturedProductsViewModel is the viewmodel?, the error message says that I can derive from ViewPage[TModel]**

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

From the controller action method you must return the view with the model object.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new FeaturedProductsViewModel());
}
```